# Webhook - caller ID from MS Teams incoming call to Jira

Tags: jira, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I´m using MS Teams with direct routing and at the same time I have an Jira account. I therefore added the Jira app in MS Teams. Works fine.
Also the direct routing from MS Teams works fine.

What I would like to do:
If I receive an incoming call in Teams, I would like to send the callerID to Jira.
In Jira I saved a pre-defined filter for surching all open tickets of this caller.

Anybody an idea how this can work.

Thanks to the community!
Chris

Expecting: Caller ID (e.g. +49176xxxxxxx) is sent from Teams to Jira App and pre-defined filter in Jira surches. I would like to see all Jira tickets of this caller in Jira - even better in Jira App of MS Teams :-)